# problema de float em python - questão simples

Tags: python, string, input, if, float

**por favor, poderiam me ajudar?**

neste código, a **entrada**, na **primeira linha**, deve conter **3 valores reais**, com uma casa decimal após a vírgula: L (0 < L <= 100), P (0 < P <= 100) e A (0 < A <= 200), correspondentes a largura, profundidade e altura de uma bagagem de mão.

**este foi o código que eu fiz:**

```
L = float(input())
P = float(input())
A = float(input())

v = float(input())

if (L <= 35, P <= 25, A <= 55, v <= 40):
 print('S')

else:
 print('N')
```

**acredito que devo usar split na entrada, certo? mas como posso transformar a string em float depois? fora isso, o que há de errado no código?**

Comment: Para evitar que o espaço de comentários se estenda, a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131885/discussion-on-question-by-i4naevis-problema-de-float-em-python-questao-simples) - Queiram tratar do assunto na [postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/535478/70)